# Bootstrap external link modal inheritance

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, slim

So I have this code that when I click `View Receipt` link, an external link to the receipt image will pop up in a modal. I am using twig and slim framework.

This is my html file with the twig:

```
{% for r in results %}
<a data-toggle="modal" href="/user/receipt/{{r.accountID}}" data-target="#myModal">View Receipt</a>
{% endfor %}

{% block script %}
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div> <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div> <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div> <!-- /.modal -->
{% endblock %}
```

The route.php code:

```
$app->get('/user/receipt/:id', function($id) use($app) {
    $db = new db();
    $bind = array(
    ":aid" => $id
    );
    $result = $db->select("accounts", "accountID = :aid", $bind);
    $app->render('screenshot.html', array('result' => $result));
});
```

The screenshot.html code:

```
{% for r in result %}
    <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <img src="/assets/img/receipts/{{r.receipt}}" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Now everything works. The image shows up in the modal. The problem is... the first time I click a `View Receipt` link when the page is being loaded, all other links will contain the same image instead of the image that is based on the `accountID`. All the links inherits the first link that is being clicked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you have a image of the problem?

Comment: After the page is fully loaded, do all the links show their respective receipt images?

Comment: @noahdotgansallo after the page is loaded and when you click a link, it will show the reciept image according to the link of the modal, w/c is correct.. but when you click another link, it shows the image of the first receipt that was clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure how to do what you're currently doing - to generate modal content dynamically - but there is an alternative.

You could instead wrap the modals in a for loop with their id pertaining to the the receipt id. Therefore, each modal only contains their respective receipt image.

```
{% for r in results %}
<a data-toggle="modal" href="/user/receipt/{{r.accountID}}" data-target="#myModal{{r.id}}">View Receipt</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Then your modal code would look something like this...

```
{% for r in results %}
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal{{r.id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div> <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div> <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

Comment: In my expert opinion I think this code is good, but not as efficient as it could be.